# Screen is black on Dell laptop and even Dell logo is not showing

Tags: dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron N5010. 3 days ago I changed hard drive of my laptop. But now I am facing one problem with my laptop.

When I try turning it on, the screen is black and all I hear is a few beeps.

It is black all the time.

Is there a problem with the hard drive or other software/hardware problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there problem with hard drive or other software/hardware problem?

Beeps indicate a hardware problem that doesn't include a Hard Drive issue.

You need to count the number of beeps and then check the following table:

> [image]
>
> Most Common Fixes:
>
> ```
> 1 Beep:  Replace the motherboard / system board.
> 2 Beeps: Reseat the memory or replace the memory.
> 3 Beeps: Replace the motherboard / system board.
> 4 Beeps: Reseat the memory or replace the memory.
> 5 Beeps: Replace the CMOS battery.
> 6 Beeps: Reseat or replace the video card or replace the motherboard / system board.
> 7 Beeps: Reseat or replace the CPU or replace the motherboard.
> 8 Beeps: Reseat the LCD cable or replace the LCD screen.
> ```

Source [Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010) Beep Codes Diagnostic Indicators](http://blog.parts-people.com/2014/06/27/dell-inspiron-15r-n5010-beep-codes-diagnostic-indicators/)